# make files available for worker nodes

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I'm relativly new to GCE and spark. I have a spark-master-instance with a mounted disk (/mnt/spark-data) which contains many files which I want to process with in my spark-cluster.
Problem: How can my worker-nodes access these files? Is there a solution, where I just need a path-String in my java-app to the files location?

I also thought about this: Copy the files from /mnt/spark-data/ to a new bucket in Google Cloud Storage - but there are 2 problems:
1) my Master-instance has no write-permission for storage, so i can't copy my files to the bucket, can I?
2) **If** I have the files in the bucket: How do I access them in my java app?

Comment: A persistent disk which I can mount on multiple instances would do what I want - as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22070494/1654763). But the chapter in the given link seems to be removed and I couldn't find any replacement.

Comment: Okay it was just [one page away](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks#use_multi_instances) - too bad it's read-only for ALL instances because I need my master to write to the disk =/

Comment: In regards to the last two points you've mentioned: 1) You can make it so the master has write permissions to the bucket, visit https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication for more info on how to do that with service accounts. 2) I don't have a specific code sample/example but you can look into https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/ for more info. There are different ways for you to upload objects and serve then via GCS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Persistent disk only can be mounted as read only to multiple GCE VM instance, so you won't be able to write to it. You may consider sharing your files between your VM instances using NFS file sharing system.

If you're going to use Google Cloud Storage, then

my answer to your first question:
You will need to create your GCE instance with full or write access to Google Cloud Storage. To do this, when you're creating the VM instance using Developers Console, click on 'Show advanced options' and select Full or Read/Write for Storage. If you use gcloud command to create VM instance then you can specify a full access to Google Cloud Storage in this way:

$ gcloud compute instances create INSTANCE --scopes storage-full

For more information about this command take a look at this link:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create

my answer to your 2nd question:
The GCS client library lets your Java application read files from and write files to buckets in Google Cloud Storage (GCS). For more information about Google Cloud Storage Java Client Library take a look at this link:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/